# Não estou conseguindo instanciar um objeto

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, eclipse

Não estou conseguindo instanciar um objeto da classe Aluno

**Classe Aluno**

```
public class Aluno extends Pessoa
{
    private int matricula;

    public Aluno(int id, String nome, String endereco, String telefone, String email, int matricula) {
        super(id, nome, endereco, telefone, email);
        this.setMatricula(matricula);
    }

    public Aluno()
    {

    }

    public int getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(int matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }
}
```

**Classe Pessoa**

```
abstract public class Pessoa 
{
    private int id;
    private String nome;
    private String endereco;
    private String telefone;
    private String email;

    public Pessoa(int id, String nome, String endereco, String telefone, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.endereco = endereco;
        this.telefone = telefone;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Pessoa() {
        super();
    }


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public String getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

**Como estou tentanto instanciar um objeto da classe Aluno porém sem êxito**

```
                    System.out.println("ID aluno:");
                    int id = input.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("Nome:");
                    String nome = input.next();
                    System.out.println("Endereço:");
                    String endereco = input.next();
                    System.out.println("Número:");
                    String numero = input.next();
                    System.out.println("Email:");
                    String email = input.next();
                    System.out.println("Matrícula:");
                    int matricula = input.nextInt();
                    aluno = new Aluno(id,nome,endereco,numero,email,matricula);
                    System.out.println("Deseja cadastrar um novo aluno?(1-Sim/2-Não):");
                    op = input.nextInt();
                    AL.add(aluno);
```

Comment: Favor [edit] a pergunta e colocar qual é o erro que ocorre, se é erro de compilação, algum `exception` que ocorre durante a execução (qual a mensagem e quais os dados que causaram o erro), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Em java você deve informar qual o tipo do objeto que se esta criando, então deve ser feito assim:

```
Aluno aluno = new Aluno(id,nome,endereco,numero,email,matricula);
```

Comment: Não é assim não amigo

Comment: @CássioElias e qual o erro que te retorna?